App center not opening
I have installed Ubuntu 24.04 twice on my HP pavilion g7 and after both installation App center still not opening. Any hint to solve the issue?

in terminal enter sudo snap refresh if your answer is any thing but All snaps up to date.  edit your answer with the info. Do not put it in comments.

And no picture pls, just copy and paste.
